# Different notations to express inheritance

Tags: generics, inheritance, scala

why are there different notations to express inheritance? In generics I have to use the <:-operator - in a normal class-inheritance I have to use the extends keyword.

For example I have to write this:

```
class X[A <: B] extends Y
```

But why not writing something like this:

```
class X[A <: B] <: Y
```

or

```
class X[A extends B] extends Y // like Java
```

I have no problem with the current notation, but I want to know whether there is a reason to notate the type hierarchy of generics in a different way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there is nothing *stopping* Scala from doing so, but, as a matter of fact, they do not express the same thing *at all*. And, in fact, you can see that in Java, where you can write `X super Y`, but you can't say `class X super Y`.

The keyword `extends` express a relationship between *classes*, one of inheritance. On the other hand, `<:` and `>:` express a relationship between *types*, one of boundaries. When I say `X <: Y`, then it is valid for both `X` and `Y` to be `String`, for example, while `String extends String` would be meaningless. It is also the case that `List[String] <: List[AnyRef]`, though, again, `List[String] extends List[AnyRef]` is meaningless. And, just to make the point, it is *not* true that `Set[String] <: Set[AnyRef]`. In all these examples I just gave we are talking about the same *class*, but not, necessarily, about the same *type*.

And, of course, there are other relationships between types, such as view bounds (`<%`) and context bounds (`:`).

So, just because `extends` implies `<:`, it doesn't follow that `<:` implies `extends`, which, alone, is reason enough to avoid using the same keyword. Add to that the *other* relationships between types, and you have pretty much a closed deal.

Comment: ++1 for talking about the difference between classes and types

Comment: regarding classes and types as different things it makes sense to use different notations. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 7):

It becomes a bit more obvious when you extend (no pun intended) your example beyond that one simple case.

Multiple inheritance:

```
class C[A] extends X with Y with Z
```

Mixins:

```
val x = new X with Y
```

Parameterization:

```
class X[A <: B] extends Y[A]
```

Multiple (related) type params:

```
class X[A >: B, B](x: A, xs: Seq[B])
```

Context bounds:

```
class X[A : Manifest]
```

View bounds:

```
class X[A <% Ordered[A]]
```

Generic *Methods*:

```
class Foo[B] {
  def bar[A <: B](x: A) = ...
}
```

As you can see, the relationships that may be specified in a type parameter are far richer than the simple linear hierarchy available when declaring a class, especially when you allow for bounds.

It's also worth noting that generic type parameters for classes or methods will very often be inferred, allowing you to write:

```
val myList = List(1, 2, 3)
```

instead of

```
val myList = List[Int](1, 2, 3)
```

So the way in which the notations are used is very different.

**update**

One particular example has just spring to mind, demonstrating the use of both notations simultaneously and showing how they need to remain distinct:

```
def someMethod[T <: Foo with Bar](x: T) = ...
```

This requires that the type-param `T` be a subtype something mixing in both `Foo` and `Bar`.

The same applies with structural types:

```
type Closable = { def close: Unit } //alias for a structural type
def someMethod[T <: Closable](x: T) = ...
```